# Block mouse key in Windows system

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, mouse, hid

My coworker uses an Icon7 Twister Evolution mouse pointer in his job and as a pointer in his presentations. As soon as he updated to Windows 10 he use a default mouse driver as the producer doesn't provide any. The problem is when he accidentally push one from two special buttons on the device, causing a strange behavior like blocking the keyboard or pushing shift key constantly, forcing my friend to restart the machine and ruin his presentations.

Is there a way to block those specific device keys system-wise?

Maybe there is a way to write such key blocker application somehow?

I've tried many of the applications like [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) or [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) but none of them work in Windows 10 properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by using pretty much from [this example](https://gist.github.com/Stasonix/3181083).

The point is to register to a low-level hook of a keyboard/mouse and by returning non-zero pointer swallow the input.